# Is it possible to merge two cms based on .NET technology?

Tags: .net, content-management-system, nopcommerce, kooboo

I want to merge 2 CMS using .NET. I want to know if it's possible to do it.

I want to use Kooboo and NopCommerce. Kooboo as the root CMS and NopCommerce will be used on a subdomain

Comment: This is a very broad and unclear question - it's not even clear what you mean by "merge 2 CMS" or where .NET would come in. Please be *much* more specific.

Comment: I want to use two cms simultaneous to give as a  result one project that work with that two CMS. I want to combine two CMS

Comment: That's still *far* too vague/broad for an answer here. I have no idea what a sensible answer to the question would look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kooboo CMS has provision for extension modules (http://www.kooboo.com/docs/kooboo-cms/module_development_43).  That means that if you would like to use Kooboo CMS as one of the building blocks of your solution then a 'module' is the most natural way for it to interact with another system.

I've not used NopCommerce before, but it looks to be a product designed for providing cataloguing and e-commerce capabilities (something which is not present in a default Kooboo CMS installation).

If your requirements are as simple as "kooboo cms with ecommerce support" then I'd suggest ignoring NopCommerce and instead look at Virto Commerce.  That is similar product but already has compatibility developed http://www.kooboo.com/products/virtocommerce

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want to combine Kooboo and NopCommerce into a single Visual Studio solution / project. **I would advise against that**.
I haven't used Kooboo, but NopCommerce's source code is quite expansive and you'll get an even more expansive result. This means that efficiency will decrease when working on code and building it. Also, it will take a good amount of work to make the two software platforms be something more than just two web apps merged into one solution.

That being said, Nopcommerce has good e-commerce capabilities and a well-structured code that is relatively easy to customize. However, it's a bit slow and demanding on the server, especially if you have a lot of content and installed plugins.

If you want to take advantage of NopC capabilities, you **could** customize the NopCommerce template to fit in with the one of Kooboo and insert relevant links into NopCommerce views to link to pages controlled by Kooboo.

You can then have NopCommerce run on the subdomain, and Kooboo on the main domain. This is a "shallow" integration that will be the most easy to implement.

One tricky part would be to build an integrated user session management. The two apps being separate, they would need to read and write user session data in a consistent (and secure) manner. This may possibly be a deal-breaker.

You will also have two different admin interfaces through this approach. That may or may not be an inconvenience.